# How we access control panel of computer by java code

Tags: java

I am trying to check in control panel that a particular .exe is install or not by using java code

Comment: Don't use Java for this.  Use a language built for Windows.  BTW - what is the relevance of this program to your application?  What application does your app. need to check for, and why?  There are easy ways, cross platform, to check for the existence of a consumer for a particular file type.

Comment: I am trying to check in control panel that a particular .exe or software is install or not by using java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to happen using only Java code. You'll need a goodly amount of native code to do the actual interaction with the control panel, package that in a DLL, and call that using JNI.
TBH I doubt you can get the data you want that way, but I'm not intimately familiar with the current Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

Java knows nothing about the Windows control panel.

Your only option would be to recursively search a directory tree to see if the .exe was present.

Java's platform-independent, so it doesn't work with parts of one operating system that aren't present in all.